# APK file size not changed after running pngcrush on over 1000 images

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk, pngcrush

I have generated a release APK file for a word game with game board and letter tile images and its size is **14.157.885 bytes**.

Then I have run [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) on about 1000 images in my Android Studio project, then "Clean Project", "Rebuild Project" and finally "Generate Signed APK..." again.

Surprisingly the resulting APK file is bigger size: **14.158.735 bytes**

[image: explorer screenshot]

I have same result with Android Studio on Windows 7 x64 and Mac OS Yosemite.

Below you can see how bitmap sizes were indeed reduced by *pngcrush* - in the git log:

[image: git screenshot]

Surely the APK file is some kind of ZIP-archive - but why has its size increased?

**UPDATE:**

The real reason for asking this question is because I include a gzipped SQLite file (size: **4.988.928 bytes**) using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) and am worried - if the APK file is small enough to run on older Android devices.

Comment: Compare the old and new APK contents and see how the compression ratios differed for the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aapt` has a `pngcrush` equivalent built in, and runs it on your input files as part of the resource packaging process. With highly-optimized input files, you may be robbing `aapt` of the opportunity to run its own optimizations.

If you'd rather use your own, you can disable aapt's through a gradle setting:

```
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

**Source:** [Issue 65335:   aapt can make PNG files larger if they have been already optimized](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65335)

Comment: So in other words I shouldn't use *pngcrush* on Android bitmap assets?

Comment: "Shouldn't" is a strong word; what I'll say is that it is unlikely to help much, and may have slight negative effects. I wouldn't go out of my way either way.